# javascript 0*this

Tags: javascript, this

I was reading some source code of a firefox extension and i saw some expression like

```
0*this;
```

dose this expression means anything ?

ps: I'm chinese, if there is some thing wrong with my English, please tell me, Thanks!

Here is a function of the extension;

```
function inGetter(){
   0*this;
   var gin=  Components.lookupMethod(this,"innerHTML")();
   gin=String.newTainted(gin,"divElement.INNERHTML");

   if(__domIntruderObj.settings.enabled  )
      __domIntruderObj.log("Getter",this.tagName+".value",gin, __domIntruderObj.util.getCallStack(arguments));
   return gin;
}
```

Comment: what's this extension kind of? could you provide chunk code example? this seems some kind of normalization.

Comment: Depends on what `this` is but it seems like it's a number so that would just be `0`.

Comment: Well, if `this` can be converted to a number, it will result in `0`. If it cannot, then it will result in `NaN`. Seems pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is part of an [XSS detection Firefox extension](http://code.google.com/p/dominator/source/browse/trunk/js/jsInject_obj_debug.js).

As mentioned in another answer, multiplication causes a call to the engine's internal `DefaultValue` method. What happens there is: it tries `valueOf` and `toString` before throwing an error. For example,

```
2 * { valueOf: function () { return 3; }} // 6
2 * { toString: function () { return '4'; }} // 8
2 * { toString: function () { return this; }} // TypeError
```

So this side-effect can be used to gain some information on the object. Particularly, there is some [custom `toString` implementation in the code](http://code.google.com/p/dominator/source/browse/trunk/js/jsInject_obj_debug.js#845), which I think this is used to generate some call stack log. I haven't really gone into the details though.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `this` in a global execution context is the global object. In a function context is can be any object, or in strict mode, any value, including undefined.

So first `this` will be converted to a primitive value using [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) (which in turn calls [DefaultValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8)), and the result will be converted to a number using [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3). The result of all that will be either a number or NaN.

So the result of `0*this` will either be `0` or `NaN`, depending on whether `this` converts to a number or `NaN` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The only tricky part I see is:

```
typeof 1 => "number"
0*1 =>  0

typeof null => "object"
0*null => 0
```

in any other case result will be `NaN`

which is also has interesting aproach bw

```
typeof NaN => "number"
```

But exactly here I guess this is smart way sort out all numbers and `null` from other types.

Comment: I doubt that. In non–strict code, `this` must be an object, and very few objects convert to numbers. It might make sense in a method added to Number.prototype, in which case `this` is likely to be a number, but that isn't guaranteed. The ambiguity with `null` needs to be explained.